# sizeof Char / Array length Memory allocation in C,

Tags: c

Can somebody tell me about the memory allocation in c?
What is the size of a char variable? 2 or 4?
Why the difference in the address value between 2 neighboring char elements in an array is only 1?

```
char foo [] = {'a', 'b'};
printf ("This is the Address of val1 %d \n", &foo[1]);           // -1079295441
printf ("This is the Address of val2 %d \n", &foo[2]);           // -1079295440
printf ("The size of each array member is %d \n", sizeof(foo));  // 2
```

Comment: `foo` is a character array and as such has the same size as any other array since it's essentially just a pointer.

Comment: "What is the size of a char variable? 2 or 4?" It's 1

Comment: @apokryfos, arrays are *not* pointers.  They have various sizes depending on their element type and capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not printing addresses correctly: an address is not an `int`, so you cannot use `%d` to print it. Use `%p` (for "pointer") instead, and cast the address to `void*` for printing:

```
printf ("This is the Address of val1 %p\n", (void*)&foo[1]);
```

Now your program produces this or similar output:

```
This is the Address of val1 0xffbd2fcf 
This is the Address of val2 0xffbd2fd0 
The size of each array member is 2
```

Two pointers are off by `1`, which is the size of a single `char`. The size of the entire array is `2`. If you want to print the size of a single element, use `foo[0]`.

Comment: @Oka There's no excessive cast in this answer

Comment: @Oka It's required. `%p` wants `void*`, so passing `int*` is considered UB.

Comment: Ah, this is an exception to the safe promotion of any pointer to `void *`. Guessing this has to do with varargs? Interesting.

Comment: @Oka Although any pointer can be used in the context where `void*` is needed (a call to a function with `void*` parameters, an assignment to a `void*` variables) `printf` has a variable-length argument list. Hence, by default pointers go unconverted.

Answer (score 0):

Memory Allocation is a bit tricky, but it's easier than you think. It is, as the name implies, the usage and selection of data to optimize program function and speed. Basically, Memory Allocation is a "perk" of languages such as C/C++ that allow programmers to only use EXACTLY as much data as needed, freeing up memory for other computer functions.

Some good info to know about memory...

- memory is known in "bytes", these are 8-bit "groups" of data.
- A "bit" is a value that is either 0 or 1.

Variable sizes:

- Char: 1 byte
- Int: 4 bytes
- double: 8 bytes

When neighboring elements are of the same type (for example, an array of chars), they will have a difference in address that increments/decrements by the value of the memory size.
Since a char variable has a size of 1 byte, neighboring elements will have addresses that differ by 1.

Ex: char addresses: 1204, 1205, 1206, 1207... (1 byte)

int addresses: 1204, 1208, 1212, 1216... (4 bytes)